# How to find least of two columns and order by the result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to find the least of two columns. I did the following..

```
select sname, least(nvl(m1,9999999),nvl(m2,9999999)) as "Least mark" from student;
```

but now, i would like to order the results by `Least mark` but I couldn't do..

```
select sname, least(nvl(m1,9999999),nvl(m2,9999999)) as "Least_mark" from student order by Least_mark;
```

since there is no such column called `Least_mark` existing in the table.

Comment: ORDER BY least(nvl(m1,9999999),nvl(m2,9999999))

Comment: I am getting the Least_mark column filled by `9999999`

Comment: ORDER BY 2 should also work - you can't use the column "as" name in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a subquery:

```
select s.*
from (select sname, least(nvl(m1,9999999),nvl(m2,9999999)) as Least_mark
      from student
     ) s
order by Least_mark;
```

Comment: The column is filled with `9999999` (all the rows)

Comment: The would probably mean that both `m1` and `m2` are `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column alias in the `order by` clause, but as you've used a quoted identifier for the alias you have to use that consistently everywhere - quoted and with exactly the same case:

```
select sname, least(nvl(m1,9999999),nvl(m2,9999999)) as "Least mark"
from student
order by "Least mark";
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99e4f/1).

You could also use positional notation, `order by 2`, but that is more likely to cause you problems in the future - say if someone inserts another column into the select list but forgets to change the positional value to match.

Worth noting that you can't use a column alias (or the positional notation) anywhere else, like a `group by` clause, in the same level of the query. To use it in a `group by` you'd have to use a subquery, as Gordon showed. It isn't necessary if you only need to order though.